# React DevTools issue in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, react-devtools

I am having an issue in Chrome only with the React DevTools. When I access my website, the React icon lights up and it acknowledges that React is in use, but the Components and Profiler tabs are not there. If I go to another website in Chrome that uses React, I can see the DevTools, so it's only my website. I've tried it on multiple computers and I still don't see those tabs. If I use Firefox React DevTools, it's works without issue. I've been digging around trying to find a solution without any luck. This issue only just began a few days ago, previously it worked just fine. The Redux-DevTools extension for Chrome does work for my website.

Comment: Follow the steps in this github issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/603#issuecomment-423111329.  enable the Allow access to file URLs by Right click on extension -> Manage extensions

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. This issue is only specific to my website.If I go to another site that is using React, I see the Components and Profiler tabs.

Comment: what's your chrome version which you are using now?

Comment: 83.0.4103.116 - most up to date version. This issue is really mind boggling, if for example I go to Bestbuy.com I see the React tools and Redux. If I go on my site, the lights are lit up for react and redux, but I cant access the devtools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get a permanent solution yet but here is the workaround :

1. Change the chrome DevTools theme, only once it is required.
2. Now open devtools, you find the extension tab in DevTools.
3. You can again change the theme whatever you want to keep and this will fix your problem.

Comment: @Mike0809 Great 